# How to write chapter/section header beside a vertical rule?

Tags: sectioning, margins, scrbook

I would like to know how to make a book page style like the following image where chapters/sections headers are alternatively printed according to page number beside a vertical rule.

[image: An example of the required page style]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
twoside=semi
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{section 1}
    \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good question!  But the answer will have very little to do with your operating system or text editor (which is why I removed those tags).  What document class are you using?

Comment: I am using "scrbook" class from "KOMA–Script".

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with some dummy content and your class etc., even if you don't know how to customise the output. People need to know your class and to see any relevant packages and configuration else their answers will be irrelevant to you.

Comment: @cfr I updated my question body. Sorry for making it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with package `fancyhdr` which allows to write page numbers and running headers elsewhere.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,blindtext}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=239mm,paperwidth=169mm,tmargin=5mm,textwidth=124mm,textheight=195mm,
  rmargin=22mm,heightrounded,includeheadfoot,headheight=5mm,headsep=8mm,foot=18mm,
  marginparsep=2mm,marginparwidth=18mm}
\usepackage[color=red,cam,a4,center]{crop}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\colorlet{TitleBlue}{blue}
\DeclareRobustCommand\headingfont{\fontfamily\sfdefault\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\def\headrulewidth{0pt}}

\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{30mm}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leavevmode\headingfont\smash{%
 \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
 \colorbox{black!80}{%
   \makebox[22mm]{\hfill
      \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
         \textcolor{white}{\fontsize{18}{19}\selectfont\thechapter}\ 
      \fi
      \rule[-2.85pt]{2mm}{12mm}%
  }%
 }}%
 \quad
  \color{TitleBlue}%<========================================
   \fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont\leftmark}%\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leavevmode\fontsize{9}{9}\headingfont
               \rightmark
               \quad
               \makebox[22mm]{}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\leavevmode% 
               \small\headingfont
               \llap{\thepage\ \rule[-13mm]{.6pt}{18mm}\hspace{1mm}}
           \hfill{\normalfont\today}% %<------ svn 
}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\leavevmode
               \small\headingfont
               {\normalfont\today}%<------ svn 
           ~\hfill \rlap{\hspace{1mm}\rule[-13mm]{.6pt}{18mm}\ \thepage}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}\blindtext[3]\par\blindtext[3]
\chapter{bar}\blindtext[7]
\chapter{baz}\blindtext[8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but would you show me an example of Latex syntax ?.

Comment: @Diaa; see example

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this question, but I am eager to understand how to make it. For your old answer, it didn't give the desired result as shown in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mM3xw.gif).

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Why do you come back almost 5 years after the answer? Are you still using `scrbook` etc classes? `fancyhdr` and KOMA stuff do not like each other!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer if you take a look at my question edit history, you will notice that I had the output of Herbert answer in my question body. However, I removed it yesterday from the question and put a link to this output in my comment for making the question body look better. So, it is not a 5 years late reply. For packages used in this question, I admit it is my mistake to not put what I am using, and I updated my question body with a MWE.